# React with Typescript: why is my array variable an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a simple To-do list application to put into practice what I'm learning, and I'm doing it in Typescript. Literally half an hour ago the application was working fine, but now "all of a sudden" (surely I touched something I shouldn't have and I'm not realizing what) I can't apply .map() on my state variable where I store the user's tasks because in theory it's an object.

**Code of the component where I create my state and define it as an array:**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import InputForm from '../InputForm/InputForm'
import ItemsContainer from './ItemsContainer'

export default function Container() {
  const [userTasks, setUserTasks] = useState(
    new Array<{ id: string; name: string; completed: boolean }>()
  )

  // This function is received by <InputForm /> and it returns the new Task.
  // Updates the current tasks (userTasks state) with the new { task } received.
  const addTaskHandler = (task: any) => {
    setUserTasks(task)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserTasks(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Task') || '{}'))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('Task', JSON.stringify(userTasks))
  }, [userTasks])

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col px-4 container mx-auto sm:max-w-screen-sm">
      {console.log(Array.isArray(userTasks(}
      <InputForm onAddTask={addTaskHandler} />
      <ItemsContainer tasks={userTasks} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Code of the component where I do the .map():**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Items from '../Items/Items'

interface Props {
  tasks: Array<{
    id: string
    name: string
    completed: boolean
  }>
}

const ItemsContainer: React.FC<Props> = ({tasks}) => {
  return (
    <ul className='h-96 overflow-auto flex flex-col items-center scrollbar-hide'>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Items name={task.name} key={task.id} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsContainer
```

I'm pretty sure that the main cause of this error must be sending me to use Typescript blindly and on the fly, but I would like to leave knowing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the reasons you should avoid using `any` when using TypeScript. Type things properly, and you'll be able to see problems during compilation, not during runtime. If you use `any`, you're defeating the purpose of using TypeScript.

With

```
const addTaskHandler = (task: any) => {
    setUserTasks(task)
}
```

It sounds like `task` is a singular element of some kind - in which case calling

```
setUserTasks(task)
```

will then set the state to *that single task* - and not an array (which will then mean that calling `.map` on it will fail).

Figure out type type of a task - it looks like it might be

```
{ id: string; name: string; completed: boolean }
```

and type the argument as that, and then append that element to the array in the handler.

```
type Task = { id: string; name: string; completed: boolean };
const [userTasks, setUserTasks] = useState<Task[]>([]);

const addTaskHandler = (task: Task) => {
    setUserTasks([...userTasks, task]);
}
```